# How to copy particular data from one file to another in a batch script

Tags: file, batch-file, copy

I am trying to copy data from a.txt to b.txt using .batch file. But i dont want the all data from a.txt. I just trying to copy perticular data.

For Example: a.txt contains

```
line 1:this is a.txt file
line 2: name= abc
line 3: age= 24
line 4: country= xyz
line 5: contact no= 123456778
line 6: end of a.txt
```

Now, I want to read that a.txt and copy particular data to new b.txt:

b.txt:

```
abc 21 xyz
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks for help.

Naren

Comment: I think you mean: `abc 24 xyz`.

Comment: yes thats correct. my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you meant `abc 24 xyz`. (Shortest answer at bottom)

This provides you with the most flexibility and cleanest variables.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Just making sure that %data% is empty
set data=

for /f "tokens=1,2* delims==" %%x in (a.txt) do call :work %%x "%%y"

:: Removes leading space and sends to b.txt
echo %data:~1%>b.txt
goto :eof

:work
set var=%1
set val=%~2

:: Remove any leading spaces.
:work-loop
if "!val:~0,1!"==" " (
  set val=!val:~1!
  goto :work-loop
)

if "%var%"=="name"    set data=%data% %var%
if "%var%"=="age"     set data=%data% %var%
if "%var%"=="country" set data=%data% %var%

goto :eof
```

Or a little shorter.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set data=
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims==" %%x in (a.txt) do call :work %%x "%%y"

:: Removes leading space and sends to b.txt
echo %data:~1%>b.txt
echo %data%>b.txt

goto :eof

:work
set var=%1
set val=%~2

:since leading spaces have not been removed, there need be no space between %data% and %var%
if "%var%"=="name"    set data=%data%%var%
if "%var%"=="age"     set data=%data%%var%
if "%var%"=="country" set data=%data%%var%

goto :eof
```

Shortest answer

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims== " %%x in (a.txt) do (
    if "%%x"=="name" set %%x=%%y
    if "%%x"=="age" set %%x=%%y
    if "%%x"=="country" set %%x=%%y
)
echo %name% %age% %country%>b.txt
endlocal
```

In this last one the use of `setlocal` and `endlocal` are not ness    :: Removes leading space and sends to b.txt
    echo %data:~1%>b.txt
icary, they just make sure your variables die when the batch file ends.

Comment: I just noticed that in the two longer solutions, `data=%data% %var%` should be `data=%data% %val%` and `data=%data%%var%` should be `data=%data%%val%`.